# Enum Class and Mixing libraries of different version in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm aware that you can't use different STL implementations in the same project, especially for things like std::vector.

I'm wondering if there is any similar issue to using `enum class` for parameters in a publicly facing API?

For example:

```
enum class MessageCategory
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

void foo(MessageCode myMessageCode);
```

Currently in my publicly facing API instead of using `enum class` I just provide them as `int`

```
void foo(int myMessageCode);
```

Comment: enums are just integers so wont change the ABI

Comment: Yes I'm aware that `enums` are just `integers` but is this really true for `enum class`

Comment: There's no runtime difference between `enum` and `enum class`, they're still just integers

Comment: What kind of issues do you expect for `enum class` and how are they related to the standard library version? Are you asking about `enum class` ABI stability w.r.t. changing a *compiler* settings/version?

Comment: When compiled to a dll, I get `public: int __cdecl foo(int) __ptr64` and 
`public: void __cdecl foo(enum MessageCode) __ptr64` respectively, so it seems that an `int` and an `enum` are not the same. My concern was that the sizeof(enum MessageCode) might not be the same as the sizeof(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enumeration type is a distinct type from its underlying type. So from the point of view of the language a function taking the underlying type and a function taking the enumeration type are distinct functions and overloads of the same name. So just changing the type in the definition of the function will in the sense of the standard cause an ODR violation for a missing definition of the original signature and the linker will complain about that.

But on all reasonable implementations the enumeration type will have the same size, alignment and representation as its underlying type (although that is technically not required by the standard at the moment).

So this is probably only a name mangling issue if you are concerned with ABI compatibility (and assuming the core language ABI is unchanged between the two versions), in that you may be able to simply coerce the linker to consider the two symbols the same.

I am saying "probably", because technically the core language ABI could e.g. specify that the calling convention handles the types differently. I haven't checked any ABI specification for that.

However, in any case, changing from the underlying type to the enumeration type is definitively an incompatible API change, as it affects overload resolution and argument conversions on calls to the function.

---

There is also one exception for `enum` enumerations (not `enum class`) without explicitly specified underlying type. The set of valid values for these may be strict subset of the set of valid values for the underlying type. In that case you can technically have an ABI difference just based on the behavior of the types, in that the compiler may be allowed to perform more aggressive optimizations on the enumeration type than the underlying type.

Comment: Thanks for providing a great and detailed answer, this was just what I was looking for.